# Window scaling broken

Tags: interface

Blender acts like my screen is larger, with some buttons being cut off entirely.

[image]

I've tried going to windowed mode and resizing it, but it won't let me resize it any wider.

Comment: Is this the full resolution of your screen? Or is Blender showing "maximized" although the window is not using the full screen? Anyway, the buttons are not variable in size, so if the screen width is not capable to show the full menu, you can scroll through it. Your picture looks like the menu is scrolled to the left. Hover your mouse over the menu bar and use the scroll wheel to move it left or right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- Change the resolution in the Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display > Resolution scale
- Maintain your preferred resolution and use the middle mouse button <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to click and drag the header menu bar